# TCC -c option error

Tags: c, tcc

I am trying to convert my `.c` file to a `.s` file using TCC, however, I get the error: `tcc: cannot specify multiple files with -c`

```
tcc.exe main.c -c main.S
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcc`, as far as I can tell, does not have an option to generate an assembly listing.

`tcc -c foo.c` takes the C source file `foo.c` as input and generates a binary object file `foo.o`.

It can also take assembly files as *input*:

`tcc -c asm.S` preprocesses and assembles the assembly source in the existing `asm.S` file and generates an object file `asm.o`.

`tcc -c asm.s` is similar, but it doesn't preprocess the input file before assembling it.

The man page says:

> TCC options are a very much like gcc options. The main difference is
>   that TCC can also execute directly the resulting program and give it
>   runtime arguments.

If tcc had an option to generate an assembly listing, then surely it would use the same option that gcc (and many other Unix-based compilers) use, namely `-S` -- but:

```
$ tcc -S foo.c
tcc: error: invalid option -- '-S'
$
```

You can get an assembly listing of sorts using `objdump`:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    puts("hello");
}
$ tcc -c foo.c
$ objdump -d foo.o

foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 81 ec 00 00 00 00    sub    $0x0,%rsp
   b:   48 8d 05 fc ff ff ff    lea    -0x4(%rip),%rax        # e <main+0xe>
  12:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  15:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  1a:   e8 fc ff ff ff          callq  1b <main+0x1b>
  1f:   c9                      leaveq 
  20:   c3                      retq   
$
```

but as you can see you lose some information that you'd get from a compiler-generated assembly listing. (Playing with `objdump` options might give you more information.)

I'm using tcc version 0.9.25 on a Linux x86_64 system.

(remyabel posted a [similar but less detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873159/827263) but deleted it, I'm not sure why.)